Why number 6 is the most frequent gap when subtracting all consecutive primes(the smaller from the larger)?
Using JavaScript, i felt like collecting all the distances between primes and see what pattern they may have. here is what i got:
i generated all primes up to a 1000000, and made an object that counts the frequency of all distances(distance:the subtraction result between a prime and the previous one. it's frequency is how many times it appeared ). below is all subtraction results(not all shown, but you can get them easily if you want, using any programming language) between primes up to a million, and an object contains each subtraction result and it's frequency.
Observation:
1- out of all subtraction results from (multiples of 2 from 1 to 144), only one multiples of 2 is missing: 94, expecting it to appear if i generate more primes and subtract more.
2- number 6(a subtraction between 2 consecutive primes) have the highest frequency.
3-the reason some of the subtraction result's frequencies are more then others, because not all the odd numbers are primes, but all primes are odd ( except number 2). so the distance between a prime an another can vary and so it's frequency.
[
1,  2,  2, 4,  2,  4,  2,  4, 6,  2,  6, 4,
2,  4,  6, 6,  2,  6,  4,  2, 6,  4,  6, 8,
4,  2,  4, 2,  4, 14,  4,  6, 2, 10,  2, 6,
6,  4,  6, 6,  2, 10,  2,  4, 2, 12, 12, 4,
2,  4,  6, 2, 10,  6,  6,  6, 2,  6,  4, 2,
10, 14,  4, 2,  4, 14,  6, 10, 2,  4,  6, 8,
6,  6,  4, 6,  8,  4,  8, 10, 2, 10,  2, 6,
4,  6,  8, 4,  2,  4, 12,  8, 4,  8,  4, 6,
12,  2, 18, 6,
... 78397 more items
]
the frequency object:
{
'1': 1,
'2': 8169,
'4': 8143,
'6': 13549,
'8': 5569,
'10': 7079,
'12': 8005,
'14': 4233,
'16': 2881,
'18': 4909,
'20': 2401,
'22': 2172,
'24': 2682,
'26': 1175,
'28': 1234,
'30': 1914,
'32': 550,
'34': 557,
'36': 767,
'38': 330,
'40': 424,
'42': 476,
'44': 202,
'46': 155,
'48': 196,
'50': 106,
'52': 77,
'54': 140,
'56': 53,
'58': 54,
'60': 96,
'62': 16,
'64': 24,
'66': 48,
'68': 13,
'70': 22,
'72': 13,
'74': 12,
'76': 6,
'78': 13,
'80': 3,
'82': 5,
'84': 6,
'86': 4,
'88': 1,
'90': 4,
'92': 1,
'96': 2,
'98': 1,
'100': 2,
'112': 1,
'114': 1
}
note: i feel like i somehow answered myself at the third observation up there. but it's worth sharing my findings. PS: i have done some math when i was young, that's all, i just came across primes in a JavaScript exercise and started thinking and googling, this is the result.
thank you.

All primes bigger than 2 are odd. The difference of two odd numbers is even. Was that what you are asking?

Nobody knows if all even numbers occur as prime gaps,  though it is conjectured that they do.

i should change my question... because i realized that since all primes are odd it's obvious that the gapes would be even... but i forgot that since i'm just a amateur programmer and not a mathematician.

From what I understand I think you might have discovered Goldbach's conjecture , or a variation of it.

Or delete the question, if that's all there was to it.

@AntonyTheo This is about prime gaps , I see no relation whatsoever to the Goldbach conjecture.

it is a conjuncture that all prime gapes are even only it is conjuncture that all primes are odd. if all prime numbers are numbers that can only be divided evenly by itself and 1, this means they are all odd, therefore all gapes are even... what i found is that up to a million data points, the gapes are all even, and no gaps between between the gaps, meaning you have all the multiples of 2 all the way to 114, except for 94.which means if i have done more then a million prime, i'll find the 94 gap. i think what i found could be useful for somebody.

@ZAK well $2 $ is a prime which is not odd also the gap from $2 \to 7$ is odd and $3 \to 7$ is even .

@AntonyTheo my search were for the gaps between consecutive primes!

@lulu Check the graph image i added. anything familiar? or why the number 6 is the most frequent?

There's a lot of research on prime gaps, and there a lot of conjectures.  Very little has actually been proven.  see this for more detail.

One pair has odd gap ($1$ between $2$ and $3$). That the others are even is trivial because $2$ is the only even prime number. So , you should restrict to odd prime numbers to rule this case out.

For small numbers , $6$ is a very common gap since for every prime $p\ge 5$ , $p+6$ is coprime to $6$ giving already a good chance to give a pair of sexy primes (assuming $p+2$ and $p+4$ are both composite). If we go to larger numbers , the most common gap will increase.

the graph looks almost like graph produced by Benford's law...the distribution of gaps is natural i would say!
